# MySQL #1064 syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO exp_pdata ( steam, exp, curlevel, nextlevel, levelnum, corbarraxp ) VALUES(STEAM:O_O_O, 0, 0, 500, 1, 1);
```

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':O_O_O, 0, 0, 500, 1, 1)' at line 1
```

I tried to search for this but didn't find what is causing this error,
Thanks for reading

Comment: Typo perhaps?  Are you just missing single quotes around `'STEAM:O_O_O'`?  Post your table structure if that doesn't resolve the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want the value as a string:

```
INSERT INTO exp_pdata ( steam, exp, curlevel, nextlevel, levelnum, corbarraxp )
    VALUES('STEAM:O_O_O', 0, 0, 500, 1, 1);
```

You need to include single quotes to delimit the value.